# Trouble adding elements to a table (array in Lua)

Tags: arrays, lua

I am attempting to create a table to serve as a small database for users:

```
users = {}

function create_new_user()
    print("Enter a unique user name (up to 12 letters): ")
    local name = io.read()
    if #name > 12 then 
        print ("That name is too long.")
        return create_new_user()
    elseif users[name] then
        print ("That name is already in use.")
        return create_new_user()
    else
        table.insert(users, 1, name)    
        print("Your new user name is: ", users[name])
    end
end
```

I understood from the manual that the line

```
table.insert(users, 1, name)
```

would insert the string value of name as an element of the users array. This is not the case-- whenever I run the script I get the following output:

```
Your new user name is:   nil
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You insert the element into the table, but you are trying to retrieve the value indexed by the  value of `name`, which is not what you stored (you are using `users[name]` instead of `users[1]`). You can probably do something like this:

```
table.insert(users, name)
print("Your new user name is: ", name)
```

Note that `table.insert(users, 1, name)` may not do what you expect as this will *prepend* elements to the table. If you insert `"abc"` and `"def"` this way, then the `users` table will include elements `{"def", "abc"}` (in this particular order). To retrieve the last inserted element you can use `users[1]`.

If you want to store values in a different order, you need to use `table.insert(users, name)`, which will *append* elements to the table. To retrieve the last element you can use `users[#users]`.

If you always want to store the added element in the first position in the table, then you can simply use `users[1] = name`.

Comment: This works great-- I used table.insert(users, name) to push the new element, and users[#users] to pop it. But how do I check to see if a user name is in use? if user[name] doesn't seem to work for this purpose, do I need to iterate over all elements, or is there a built in function for this?

Comment: @etothepowerofx You'd have to do a linear search of the array. Much simpler (and more efficient, not that it matters here) to use the name as a key, as shown in my answer, so that your search is just a hashtable lookup.

Comment: @etothepowerofx, as Mud said, you can simply keep track of existing users in the same table using it as hashtable; when you added a new users, also store `users[name] = true` and when you removed (poped) a user, also remove it from the hash part (`users[name] = nil`). This way you can always use `users[name]` to quickly check if you have the user or not.

Comment: @Mud Thanks to you both, your answers were equally helpful.  I've determined it's best to approach this as a table rather than an array based on your recommendation. I chose this as my answer because it was first.

Answer (score 3):

Here you index the user table with a string (the name):

```
 elseif users[name] then
```

You do the same here:

```
 print("Your new user name is: ", users[name])
```

But you *store* the name with a *numerical* index:

```
 table.insert(users, 1, name)
```

What you want instead of that line is:

```
users[name] = name
```

Or this (which would require changing the line that follows):

```
users[name] = true
```

The idea is you're only really using the keys, to create a lookup table.

Comment: Would I be creating a name key/value pair by using users[name] = name, where both the key and the value are the name string?

Comment: Yes. You could really use anything want as the value, since you're not really using it (it just needs to be something other than `nil` or `false` for your name check to work). There's nothing preventing you from, say, using `user[name] = {}` and then using `user[name].password = password`, `user[name].lastlogin = os.time()`, so on and so forth.